# how to dynamically update listview based on values of class

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a contact book application wherein I have a listview with a add button. On clicking the add button it redirects the user to a modal page asking for it's name, email id, institution. All of this details are saved in a ContactDetails class. On clicking done button on the modal page I want to display the contents in my listview.

Any suggestions on how to implement this successfully.

Code am currently working on are as follows:
ContactDetails.cs

```
public class ContactDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Inst { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set;}  
    public int Mob { get; set;}
}
```

ContactDetailsModalPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class ContactDetailsModalPage: ContentPage
{
    CandidateDetails cd = new CandidateDetails();
    async void OnDoneClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        cd.Name = (string)candNameEntry.Text; 
        cd.Inst = (string)candInst.Text;
        cd.EmailId = (string)candEmailId.Text;
        cd.Mob = Convert.ToInt32(candMobNumber.Text);

        List<ContactDetails> candList = new List<ContactDetails>();
        candList.Add(cd);

        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();

    }


    public CandidateDetailsModalPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
}
```

I am not able to understand as to what should I provide as the itemsource for my listview so that it can dynamically display the value that are stored in the ContactDetails class by modal page.

Comment: In Xamarin Forms, any property i.e `candList` assigned to `[ListView]` will automatically listen to the changes and will update the view!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an ObservableCollection instead of a List.  An ObservableCollection will notify any data bound element of changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you're giving us too little information.

1. Are you using the MVVM pattern? If not: You need a reference to the `ListView` and add a new Cell. If yes: Please post your `ViewModel` holding the bound `ContactDetails` List.
2. Like @Jason said, if there is a List of `ContactDetails` that is bound to the `ItemsSource`of the `ListView` - it needs to be an `ObservableCollection<ContactDetails>`. All you have do do in your ClickHandler is to get a reference to that List and add / insert the new item.